# Populate radio button options dynamically

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, wrapper-class, lightning-radiogroup

I am trying to set a radio button's options dynamically. I'm first constructing a wrapper list in my first component and passing the list to another component where I'm displaying the values.

Apex Controller:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static Map<String,List<surveywrapper>> Questions(String partnerName,List<String>selectedCommitteeList){
        Map<String,List<surveywrapper>> surveyMap = new Map<String,List<surveywrapper>>();
        for(Survey_Question_Bank__c survey: [Select Id,Mandatory__c,Question__c,Question_Literal_Backend__c,Section__c,Sub_Section__c FROM Survey_Question_Bank__c ORDER BY Section__c DESC]){
            surveywrapper wrap = new surveywrapper();
            wrap.question = survey.Question__c;
            if(survey.Question_Literal_Backend__c == 'Committee'){
                wrap.optionList = selectedCommitteeList;
            }else{
                wrap.optionList.add('Strongly Disagree');
                wrap.optionList.add('Agree');
            }

            if(surveyMap.containsKey(survey.Section__c)){
                surveyMap.get(survey.Section__c).add(wrap);
            }else{
                surveyMap.put(survey.Section__c, new  List <surveywrapper> { wrap });
            }

        }

        return surveyMap;
    }
```

Wrapper class in apex:

```
public class surveywrapper{

        @AuraEnabled public string question{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public string questionId{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public List<String> optionList{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public List<StringWrapper> finaloptionList{get;set;}
        public surveywrapper(){
            mandatory = false;
            selected = false;
            optionList = new List<String>();
            finaloptionList = new List<StringWrapper>();
        }
    }
public class StringWrapper{
        public String option;
    }
```

Controller of the first lightning component:

```
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS" && component.isValid()) {
                    console.log('response.'+response.getReturnValue());
                    var result = response.getReturnValue();
                    var arrayMapKeys = [];
                    var returnVal = [];
                    for(var key in result){
                        returnVal = result[key];
                        var finalresult = [];
                        var finalList = [];
                        for(var i=0; i<returnVal.length; i++){
                            var options = returnVal[i].optionList;
                            var finaloptions = [];
                            for(var j=0; j<options.length; j++){
                                finaloptions.push({'label':options[j],'value':options[j]});
                                returnVal[i].finaloptionList.push(finaloptions);
                            }

                        }
                        finalresult = returnVal;
                        arrayMapKeys.push({key: key, value: finalresult});
                    }
                    component.set("v.questions", arrayMapKeys);
                }
            });
```

Response in console:

```
Section_Name: Array(4)
0: {finaloptionList: Array(2), optionList: Array(2), question: "Question1" …}
```

I am now passing {!v.questions} to another component where I'm displaying the radio button

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.questions}" var="mapKey" indexVar="key">
            <aura:iteration items="{!mapKey.value}" var="quest" >
                    <ui:outputText value="{!quest.question}" class="slds-text-heading_small"/>  

                    <lightning:radioGroup class="customRadioCls" aura:id="options"
                                      name="feedback"
                                      label=""
                                      options="{! quest.finaloptionList }"
                                      disabled="true"
                                      />
            </aura:iteration>
        </aura:iteration>
```

The final screen is shown as 
[image]

The options are coming blank. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you setting `arrayMapKeys` to  `v.questions` attribute , but  you pushed list of objects in to `arrayMapKeys` object shape key value properties but in` aura:iteration` using  `finaloptionList ` it's not correct. better to create wrapper class with label and value properties then you can get and use list<wrapper class> directly in `aura:iteration`

Comment: @sdandamud1 could you please elaborate?

Comment: can you post `surveywrapper` structure and can you post format of `result ` in js controller?

Comment: I've made changes to the question

Comment: your not setting any values for `finaloptionList` property of `surveywrapper` in Apex method, but in your `Response in console:` shows  `{finaloptionList: Array(2)`  so your `Response in console:` is customized response at before setting to` v.Question` i think.  so what i understood is your trying to set the `finaloptionList `  by using `optionList` with binding the `label` and    `value` for each option then each option push in to `finaloptionList ` is it right?

Comment: Yup that’s right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I realized my mistake.

In my lightning controller:

```
for(var j=0; j<options.length; j++){
                                finaloptions.push({'label':options[j],'value':options[j]});
                                returnVal[i].finaloptionList.push(finaloptions);
                            }
```

The above code was inserting an array inside an array. I modified my code to

```
for(var j=0; j<options.length; j++){
                                    returnVal[i].finaloptionList.push({'label':options[j],'value':options[j]});
                                }
```

This fixed the issue

Comment: Glad you solved it. Don't forget to make your answer as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

[lightning:radioGroup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:radioGroup/documentation) is itself a container to show the Radio Buttons using attribute for Options. In your code basically you are showing a list of "empty" radio groups by iterating through `aura:iteration`.

See the Salesforce example as below. You need to specify the options in an attribute.

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
    {'label': 'apples', 'value': 'option1'},
    {'label': 'oranges', 'value': 'option2'}
    ]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" default="option1"/>
    <lightning:radioGroup
        aura:id="mygroup"
        name="radioButtonGroup"
        label="Radio Button Group"
        options="{! v.options }"
        value="{! v.value }"
        onchange="{! c.handleChange }"
        required="true" />
</aura:component>
```

You have to update your codes in similar lines

JS Controller

```
var finaloptions = [];
for(var j=0; j<options.length; j++){
    finaloptions.push({'label':options[j],'value':options[j]});
}
component.set("v.optionsList",values);
```

Component Markup

```
<aura:attribute name="optionsList" type="List" /> 
 ............
 ............
<lightning:radioGroup class="customRadioCls" aura:id="options"
        name="radioButtonGroup"
        label="Radio Button Group Title"
        options="{!v.optionsList}"
        value="{!v.value}" />
```

Comment: But what if I want to set the options dynamically? Also {! quest.finaloptionList } shows the following in the console :
Array(2)
0: {label: "Strongly Disagree", value: "Strongly Disagree"}
1: {label: "Agree", value: "Agree"}

Comment: Yes, you can do it dynamically by updating the attribute with your JS array. I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: The edit you’ve made above won’t work for me I guess. I'm displaying the options from a list of wrapper class. Kindly go through my apex controller.

Answer (score 0):

i have done some Customization based on our conversation in comments area about your Question,i got
 following Apex Response in to JsController. let me know if any further customization needed.

```
    {  
   "section1":[  
      {  
         "finaloptionList":[  

         ],
         "optionList":[  
            "Strongly Disagree",
            "Agree"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "section2":[  
      {  
         "finaloptionList":[  

         ],
         "optionList":[  
            "Strongly Disagree",
            "Agree"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "section3":[  
      {  
         "finaloptionList":[  

         ],
         "optionList":[  
            "Strongly Disagree",
            "Agree"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**ApexController**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String,List<surveywrapper>> Questions(String partnerName,List<String>selectedCommitteeList){
    Map<String,List<surveywrapper>> surveyMap = new Map<String,List<surveywrapper>>();
    List<String> sectionslist = new List<String>{'section1','section2','section3'};
    for(String str : sectionslist){
        surveywrapper wrap = new surveywrapper();


            wrap.optionList.add('Strongly Disagree');
            wrap.optionList.add('Agree');


        if(surveyMap.containsKey(str)){
            surveyMap.get(str).add(wrap);
        }else{
            surveyMap.put(str, new  List <surveywrapper> { wrap });
        }

    }

    return surveyMap;
}
```

**cmpController**

```
({
onInit: function (component) {
    var action = component.get("c.Questions");
   action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS" && component.isValid()) {                    
                var result = response.getReturnValue();
                var mapwrapper = []; 
                console.log('response.'+result);
                Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
                    var sectionElement = {};
                    sectionElement.Id = key;
                    sectionElement.Value =[];
                    var surveywrapperObjectlist =result[key];
                    console.log(surveywrapperObjectlist);
                    surveywrapperObjectlist.forEach(function(SWobj){
                        var sectionRadioitem ={};
                        SWobj.optionList.forEach(optionitem =>{
                            sectionElement.Value.push({'label' : optionitem, 'value':optionitem });
                        });
                    });
                   mapwrapper.push(sectionElement);

                });
       console.log(mapwrapper);
       component.set("v.questions", mapwrapper);
            }
   });          


    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

**cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="SeTesting" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
        access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="questions" type="List"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.questions}" var="mapKey" indexVar="key">
    <lightning:card title="{!mapKey.Id}">

                <lightning:radioGroup class="customRadioCls" aura:id="options"
                                  name="feedback"
                                  label=""
                                  options="{! mapKey.Value }"
                                  disabled="true"/>
    </lightning:card>
    </aura:iteration>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. But I need to display the question attribute which is being populated in my apex controller and not the map's keys. Also, I have a couple more parameters in my wrapper class like 'selected' and 'mandatory' which are skipped in your answer. What should be done about those?